# Nodejs (express) running but requests not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pm2

I run my project backend 'server.js' (express). it's working correctly and without any problem. But I send a request from Postman or another apps, I can not get any response or error. Only loading.
Sometimes it works fine and I get all requests correctly but after few minutes or hours I cannot get any request responses.
Please help me. What is cause this problem?
I'am using Reactjs, Nodejs (express)

Comment: The problem is within your code, you need to include it, so we can figure out the issue.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. As @k0hamed mentioned, we need to see what you've tried (your code) so we can help debug what's happening. A minimal example is best. Check out this post on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code as global error handling in your staring file. and you will get all error res as json.

because chances are you might be having typo in your url. so with this code in place you will get .. not fount error res  ...  as json.

```js
    
    // route not found
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
     const error = new Error('Not found');
     error.message = 'Invalid route';
     error.status = 404;
     next(error);
    });
   // log errors to console
    app.use(logErrors);
     //
    app.use(clientErrorHandler);
    app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
      return res.json({
      status:error.status || 500,
      message: error.message,
      error: {
      error: error.message,
      },
    });
   });

// log errors to console
function logErrors(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  next(err);
}
// error handling for xhr request
function clientErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    //console.log('xhr request');
    res.status(400).send({status: 400, message: "Bad request from client", error: err.message });
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
}

let port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way for using express js, maybe you can try.

First, you must input the detail of you app.

```
npm init
```

Second, you must install Body Parser and Express

```
npm install body-parser express --save
```

Third, place this code to you main js (e.g. server.js or index.js what you input in npm init )

```js
const BodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
const Express = require( 'express' );
const App = Express();

// Parse request of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
App.use( BodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );

// Parse request of content-type - application/json
App.use( BodyParser.json() );

App.listen( 3000, () => {
 console.log( "Server Run:" + 3000 );
} );

App.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
 res.json( {
  status: "OK"
 } );
} );

App.get( '/test', function( req, res ) {
 res.json( {
  status: "Hehehe Test"
 } );
} );
```

Fourth, start the node

```
node server.js
```

Now, you can access your code in browser

```
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/test
```